# Is it possible to have an app with a deployment target of iOS 5 to be accepted to the app store?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I currently have an app with the deployment target of iOS 5. Does Apple have a minimum accepted app store target? I'm currently rebuilding the app with the iOS 8 SDK, but was just wondering if it was possible to keep the target that low without them rejecting it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

not that i know of. I would suggest not worrying about anything under ios 6 because of the number of users who are on that version of ios. Its not worth the hassle or the time for it to possibly be rejected. If you have any other doubts on if your app could be rejected it is worth reading the guidelines for apps on apples developer website. Good luck with your app!

Comment: All the first generation iPads out there are maxed out as ios5, a lot of developers still support iOs5 for this very reason.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. The lowest you can set your deployment target while still supporting arm64 is iOS 5.1.1

This won't appear in the drop down menu in Xcode anymore but just type it in there.

(I last had an update approved with deployment 5.1.1 around a month ago)